# Pure linear birth process

Tags: probability

I can't find proof that pure linear birth process has the form of a negative binomial distribution:
$$
P_{ij}(t)={j−1\choose i−1}e^{−iλt}(1−e^{−λt})^{j−1},j≥i.
$$
I am trying to proove it with Kolmogorov equations.

Comment: What do you call $P_{ij}(t)$?

Comment: Probability to move from state i to state j during the time t.

Comment: Then the result should depend on $j-i$ and $t$ only, no?

Comment: No, λ is also important, it is the intensity to grow

Comment: Something feels off. The usual equation is 

$$P_n(t)=\binom{n-1}{n_0-1}e^{-\lambda n_0t}(1-e^{-\lambda t})^{n-n_0}$$. Are you sure the second part is raised to $j-1$ and not say, $j-i$?

Where $n_0$ is the initial population.

Comment: You are right, the last part is raised to j-i. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off my comment,

$$P_n(t)=\binom{n-1}{n_0-1}e^{-\lambda n_0t}(1-e^{-\lambda t})^{n-n_0}$$

where $n_0$ is the initial population and $n$ is the final population. Show from first principles that $P_n'(t)$ satisfies the recurrence:

$$P'_n(t)=-n\lambda P_n(t)+(n-1)\lambda P_{n-1}(t)$$

This can be done by taylor expanding $P_n'(t+h)$ to first order, and showing the higher order terms involving $h$ die when everything is rearranged. This is exactly the recurrence of the negative binomial distribution with parameters $p=e^{-\lambda t}$ and $q=1-p$. You can do this backwards by showing that the negative binomial distribution has generating function:

$$\phi_n(z)=\left(\frac{pz}{1-qz}\right)^{n_0}$$

which satisfies the above recurrence when converted to a generating function.